# Facebook graph: error in after cursor

Tags: facebook-graph-api

when I make a get request on facebook graph api, for page search, everything is fine. But when I use the after cursor or click on the 'next' field I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1,
        "fbtrace_id": "B4oyy5hYamh"
    }
}
```

until yesterday everything worked perfectly, but today I found this problem.

this is my first request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?access_token=*******&fields=about,paging&type=place&center=41.817557,12.446137&categories=["FOOD_BEVERAGE"]&distance=2000&limit=25
```

and this is the request for the next page:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?access_token=*******&fields=about,paging&type=place&center=41.817557,12.446137&categories=["FOOD_BEVERAGE"]&distance=2000&limit=25&after=QWJwc3kyZAklVTVpZAMmlEd0hFdXRINWVOU2hPSDQ5SWtYcXFreHFGX2pTVndHMW9DOV9BTmgtVGlxN04xUDJheXRCSGZAabjZAxUVJnbE5wRmcyMU4yQ3J3ZAkRqVVE1NHpjQWhPZAkh5clA1MnUxNV9WTzU1TngzYlhfVkRfZAGs2SWZAkNXNFQ3RQWEd2Rk1hNXdGRW5vdmlNbFh3aDl4YzlSdmxWUkQ4RzFGTnFZAbUxqYzhnMFZASYkxuWHJobUttSkdwZAWZANUnkwN1AyQm93Tnh1bnYwT0ZAEMVRyYXhZAMldFNF9SNjlCMGttWmZA6SGdKSUN4aXZAyLVZAmOUJ4RnM3SFJRNHNUY3lUNDUyOGo2VTdrWUJYcDh3SVd2dDdOWlBzZAUhPZA0tzY0czM25hU25iNmI0ZATN0UFFQZAGlJSFdEd2J3bVUycUZAvNE5YVEw4QlJmTUJmNlpvUWd0Y1pQOE9aWnpKOFlkZAFIxcTU2UXBJTzRR
```

Answer (score 0):

Your after seems incorrect, it should be a very short code. Have you pasted an access token instead?

This query
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=food&type=page&limit=3&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN returns

```
{
data: [
{
name: "Food Network",
id: "20534666726"
},
{
name: "FOODbible",
id: "996909263665350"
},
{
name: "Food",
id: "113109208703114"
}
],
paging: {
cursors: {
before: "MAZDZD",
after: "MgZDZD"
},
next: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search?access_token=ACCESSTOKEN&pretty=1&q=food&type=page&limit=3&after=MgZDZD"
}
}
```

so to fetch the next list, I simply append the after value (MgZDZD) to my initial query to fetch the next page of results. eg
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=food&type=page&limit=3&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&after=MgZDZD